# How to write file in root level directory rather than app data directory in Cordova android app?

Tags: android, cordova

I am building a Cordova android application and use `cordova-plugin-file` to write file on local system. The code I am using is as below:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {

    console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
    fs.root.getFile("newPersistentFile.txt", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {

        console.log("fileEntry is file?" + fileEntry.isFile.toString());
        writeFile(fileEntry, null);

    }, onErrorCreateFile);

}, onErrorLoadFs);
```

The file `newPersistentFile.txt` will be created inside `app` data directory. How can I write file into system root level directory such as `/Downloads`, `Notifications`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the cordova.file directories (see [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#android-file-system-layout)).

So for downloads:

```
window.requestFileSystem(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "Downloads", 0, function(fs) {
   console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
   ...
}
```

Comment: I have checked that the `externalRootDirectory` is in `/storage/emulator/0/Android/data` directory.

Comment: Yeah, that is the root of where Downloads, Android, DCIM, Pictures, etc is.  /storage/emulator/0/Android is the same as /sdcard.

Comment: Actually it is not the root folder where Downloads exist. The downloads folder is in `/Downloads`.

Comment: Actually externalRootDirectory is ``file:///storage/emulated/0/`` (depending on how the device is structured, which version of android, etc).  Downloads is one directory underneith that.  There is no /Downloads directory, that is just a construct that a file browser will show you since as a user you aren't allowed to go back beyond //storage/emulated/0/.  Boot up Android Studio and go to Device Browser if you want to see the directory structure.  The above code will work, and give a filesystem in the downloads directory...